# Compare columns of two different dataframes row-wise - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes as follows:

```
df1 =

     col_1   val_1
0    4.0     0.89
1    4.0     0.56
2    49.0    0.7
3    49.0    1.23
4    52.0    0.8
```

```
df2 =
     col_2   val_2
0    3.0     9
1    4.0     23.0
2    49.0    85
3    50.0    34
4    52.0    75
```

I want to compare the columns `col_1` of the dataframe `df1` and `col_2` of the dataframe `df2` row-wise and see if there is a match which is indicated by True or False.

for example:

```
df1 =

     col_1   val_1  Match
0    4.0     0.89   False
1    4.0     0.56   True
2    49.0    0.7    True
3    49.0    1.23   False
4    52.0    0.8    True
```

I tried the following but it did not give me the desired results:

```
df1['Match'] = df1.apply(lambda row: all(i in df2.col_2for i in df1.col_1), axis=1)
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check each row.
Boolean will be assigned in the new column `match`

```
df1['Match'] = df1['col_1'] == df2['col_2']
```

```
Output:

   col_1  val_1  Match
0    4.0   0.89  False
1    4.0   0.56   True
2   49.0   0.70   True
3   49.0   1.23  False
4   52.0   0.80   True
```